# SSAS DMV's NOT LIKE Condition

Tags: sql, ssas, sql-like, dmv

I have the query that runs OK on SSAS.

```
SELECT  DIMENSION_NAME
FROM  $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS
WHERE LEFT(CUBE_NAME,1) = '$'
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] <> '[Metrics]'
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] <> '[Measures]'
ORDER BY DIMENSION_NAME
```

How should I specify `NOT LIKE` condition to get all `Dimension Names` that do not start with "`Fact`"? In T-SQL it is written such as

```
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] NOT LIKE 'Fact%'
```

but how to write it in MDX?

---

Edit based on comments:

How to write the query so I can filter out elements starting with "`Fact`" in the name?

The following query returns an error:

```
SELECT  DIMENSION_NAME ,*
FROM  $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS
WHERE LEFT(CUBE_NAME,1) = '$'
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] <> '[Metrics]'
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] <> '[Measures]'
AND [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] NOT LIKE 'Fact%'
ORDER BY DIMENSION_NAME
```

-

```
Executing the query ...
Query (6, 29) The syntax for 'NOT' is incorrect.
Execution complete
```

Comment: DMV are not meant to be written in MDX. MDX is for querying cube's data, where DMV's are meant for querying cube properties.

Comment: Maybe I shuffled the terms a bit. What I want to do is to run this on SSAS server in SSMS to get the cube properties, but filter the dimensions / elements by name.

Comment: I agree with SouravA - stick to sql: I think the dmv will be a relational table and hence mdx will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the second last line with this:

```
AND LEFT([DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME], 4) <> 'Fact'
```

Hope you are running the statement in a new `DMX` query window on `SSMS`

Comment: Yes, that actually clever. I will play around with this as the unique name starts with [ .. as [unique_name] .. but that should be OK. Thanks.